# How to use BackgroundWorker to show progress of reading CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, backgroundworker

I have a very large CSV file (~5.5GB) which I am trying to read to show row count to see how long it takes to complete the process. The issue I am having is since it is a large file, whenever I try to read the file my application hangs, could be that it's busy reading or just frozen. So I want to integrate a background worker to show progress in my application.

I have a `ProgressBar (pb)`, a `Label (label1)`, a `TextBox (textBox1)`, and a `Button (button)`

My application code looks like the following:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.Text = @"\\svr\CreFiles\ndaa_2011.csv";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int i = 0;
     BackgroundWorker worker;
     worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
     worker.DoWork += (senders, args) =>
     {
       using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(textBox1.Text))
       {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                  //Processing row
                  string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                  foreach (string field in fields)
                  {
                       //TODO: Process field
                       i++; //add 1 to i for each row to get a total row count
                       label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
                       {
                           label1.Text = "" + i;
                       });
                       worker.ReportProgress(i); //maybe the calculation needs to be different?
                  }
            }
       }
    };
    worker.ProgressChanged += (senders, args) =>
    {
       pb.Value = Math.Min(args.ProgressPercentage, 100); //maybe this needs to change?
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I ran the application and I don't see any change in the `ProgressBar`.

What I am looking to do is no matter the number of rows the progress should change from 0 to 100% based on the row count.

Does my code need to be modified in any way?

**Update**:

I updated my question and added the label and the background worker progress inside the `foreach` statement and the label is changing showing how many rows it's reading. But how do I find the calculation for the progress? The progressbar fills up as soon as I hit the button.

Comment: If you only report progress after you read everything, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: That's probably because you're sending too much work to the UI thread.  You should only report progress when there is a noticeable change (eg, 1%).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Updated my question to include those lines inside the foreach statement. I would like to know how to calculate that percentage :/

Comment: Actually, you can't, since you have no idea how long the file is.

Comment: I guess then, not show a progress and just display the label as it's reading the rows?

Comment: That would work, but you still shouldn't update too frequently.

Comment: Well what would you recommend? I would like to show some sort of progress that way the user doesn't think it's hung

Comment: @Sam: That's number of bytes, not number of rows.

Comment: I'd recommend to show the user how much data it already read, then the users sees it's doing something, without having to show how much it still has to do.

Comment: I am wondering then if I should show the label update as it reads the rows and then show progress when writing somewhere (sql table for example)?

Comment: @SLaks Yes, but if he calculates the average length of each row as he's reading he can still get an estimate.

Comment: @private_meta So displaying the label update to show as it's reading is a good enough implementation?

Comment: I wouldn't update on EVERY read line, that would in my opinion overload the UI thread. For example every 100 lines output how many lines/bytes were read (You have the amount of data, you can calculate the bytes if you want). And yes, updating a label should be enough.

**Edit:** If you want a precise status update, you have to think about how much work you're doing just to show the user that work is being done, maybe it's not worth it.

Comment: I don't mind even every 150 lines. How would I implement it? :/

Comment: Is this line: `foreach (string field in fields)` doing for every line or for every field in a line?

Comment: `if (i%150 == 0) { worker.ReportProgress(i); }` would be an example. You can either submit the number of lines, or if you're fancy, the number of bytes, and display that.

Comment: I think it's currently reading each fields? How can I modify so it reads for each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using `i` value (i.e. the line number) to report the progress of the application, which unless the file is exactly 100 lines long, would produce the wrong percentage computation.

The only indication of how long the job would take is the length of the file you are processing; however, this length is in `bytes` and each line does not exactly correspond to a specific number of bytes. You can compute the number of `byte`s each `string` line has base on the fact each `char` takes about a `byte` using ASCII encoding (this changes in Unicode, which might be 1, 2, or 4 bytes per char). You can use that value to update the percentage based on the cumulative sum and the length of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think my code is currently reading each fields rather than line? I am trying to make it so that it reads the line.

Comment: It would be better to use the stream's position.

Comment: @SLaks Agreed; simpler even. But given the current implementation, this might be simpler to adapt.

Comment: 20 + (n/2) * 4 would be applicable if you need the size of a string in your memory. That's not important here, what's important is the size of a string in the file, and that doesn't have any overhead.

Comment: @private_meta: That depends on the file's encoding.

Comment: Thank you for the calculation. I will try and implement it and take all the ideas.

Comment: @private_meta I updated the answer to include the new bytes per string formula based on ASCII encoding (and a note about Unicode).

Answer (score 2):

As you are reading pure Text, I assume, You can get the amount of bytes you are reading by using the method `Encoding.Default.GetByteCount(string)`. Using that you could sum up how much Data is read in bytes. **Edit:** Alternatively, instead of Default Encoding, take the encoding of the file here.

You can also get the filesize of your current file in bytes, just use the appropriate file system method.

The amount of updates you need depends entirely on you, you can do it every 100 reads, you can do it every 100 lines, every 100 and so on.

You can update your progress bar by setting it to `(NumberBytesRead/NumberBytesTotal)*100`
This will give you a percentage of the read bytes. You might want to add the offset of commas, newlines, and other things to correct the calculation as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you. I will implement it.